# Processing (sending/receiving) UDP data in background

Tags: ios, xamarin, background, task

I'm developing an app in Xamarin for iOS/Android that will send and receive data using UDP.

Would it be possible to do this while the app is running in the background or even when the screen has gone to sleep?

Much like when Facebook Messenger app is in an active call.

Comment: i was working with same stuff here, seems like the only possible way to do it is by using native implementation. i dont really know about iOS, but in android you need to access the download manager api, since each android / device has its own download manager. i haven't try with UDP i was working with HTTP download. Please share some info if you get something about this, because i want to know it aswell

Answer (score 0):

Short answer (for iOS): No. Background fetch is opportunistic, you can't just force it. Remote notifications can be triggered remotely but the processing time is limited.

VoIP apps use libraries provided by Apple to perform those tasks (E.g: PushKit, CallKit), and also make use of VoIP Background mode. Have a look at [Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html). You can't just download content in the background whenever you want though, there are limits (in notifications, data processing, etc.)

On Android, you can use [Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html), *that can perform long-running operations in the background, and it does not provide a user interface.*

The closest to Android Services are [Remote Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW57) or [Background fetch](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW56). Allowed background execution modes (excerpt):

> - Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background, such as a music player app
> - Apps that record audio content while in the background
> - Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as a navigation app
> - Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
> - Apps that need to download and process new content regularly
> - Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories
>
> Declaring the services lets the system know which services you use, but in some cases it is the system frameworks that actually prevent your application from being suspended.

Background fetch caveat:

> Enabling this mode is not a guarantee that the system will give your app any time to perform background fetches

Comment: Is this true for iOS even if the device is charging?
My app will require that the charger is connected.

Comment: Have you submitted a version of your app to the AppStore ? I doubt Apple will allow you to force the device to be plugged in

Comment: No not yet. Why would that be the case? I'm thinking that if the device is charging, then background operations could be used for an extended period of time.

Comment: I don’t think I’ve seen such restrictions in other apps.

Comment: The only allowed use cases for background usage are the ones documented in the link above